# Multiple identical rows in a table, how to trigger one onclick event?

Tags: jquery

I have rows in a table, with a click event triggered by an anchor. Each row is identical, and the click event shows an div whilst hiding another. How do I only trigger the onclick event relating to the corresponding li which is on the same row?

Here is the jQuery I'm using

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        $('.split-trigger').click(function() {  
            $(this).toggleClass('splittrigger-active');
            $('.split').toggleClass('split-active');     
        });  
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

To only apply changes via the .click() event, I used .siblings() to the trigger element like so:

```
(function($) {
        $(document).ready(function() {  
            $('.split-trigger').click(function() {  
                $(this).toggleClass('splittrigger-active');
                $(this).siblings('.split').toggleClass('split-active');     
            });  
        });
    })(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(this).closest("tr")` to find the containing row of the table. Then you can find the elements within this to toggle.

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        $('.split-trigger').click(function() {  
            $(this).toggleClass('splittrigger-active');
            $(this).closest("tr").find('.split').toggleClass('split-active');     
        });  
    });
})(jQuery);
```